# Вывод значения из БД

Tags: mysql

Нужно вывести значение из бд, оно выводится, но с дополнительными данными.

Код:

```
$emailq = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE login='$u_login'");
$email = mysql_fetch_assoc($emailq);
print_r($email);
```

Что выводится:

```
Array ( [email] => test@mail.ru )
```

Как подправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил сам.

```
$emailq = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE login='$u_login'"));
echo $emailq["email"];
```

Comment: SQL Injection